# Google oauth2.0 with a web app for an organization?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm attempting to pull calendar data (FreeBusy query) for employees in our orgs for a web app so that users can know whether or not they should contact that user right now. When trying to hit the FreeBusy api endpoint I get a 403 as expected, how can I authenticate with Google to allow this user (or app) to pull the information from the API?

Is it possible to create an "app authorization" token with a client username/password to pull this data from the google dev console? Or do I have to use some sort of redirect to google auth url and let the user authenticate there and provide a callback url?

Alternatively, is there any way to include google auth when the page loads? Is there a way to sort of "pop up" the google account you want to use and let google then generate an access token based on that?

The simple flow looks like this:

1. User enters some data about what they need into a frontend form (javascript app)
2. Call my own API and determine which employees match X criteria.
3. Take this result set and check the calendars of these matches. If they're available then allow user to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access data of other employees, not one that initiated the request, you will either need those employees to each consent to your use of their data or (this is what would generally be done) get the admin of your organization to approve your app on behalf of all users in the domain.

If you do the latter, you can use domain-wide delegation [1] using a service account to pull the information you need.

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority

Comment: When I pull the data from another user in my org I'm able to still pull the FreeBusy data it appears? It doesn't tell me what the "busy" is but I still get an array back with the busy times. I believe our calendars are set up to allow anyone in org to see them, but user has to change settinga to actually see the details of those busy times? So realistically any user who auths on the site with an email in our domain could pull the "busy" list it appears. (in this use case the details of the busy time are irrelevant)